# Compiling user's code on a Rails App (on Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, superuser

I'm trying to implement a code compiling-running-checking opperation (codepad.org like) on my Ruby on Rails App, hosted on Heroku, but I'm missing some of the concepts.

I know that I should use a VM or a chroot jail to run those codes on the server side for security reasons, checking and returning the output of the compilation to the user. However, I have no clue how to do the following steps on Heroku:

1. to install the needed compilers to my dyno/app
2. to run untrusted scripts on Heroku: (a) commands in a VM or (b) on a chroot jail

Comment: I would suggest removing the last two tags. Maybe ask this on superuser?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @HunterStevens!